# How to make picturebox move along edges of screen without clipping?

Tags: c#, winforms

In a sample car game, I want to be able to make the car move within the screen, and I want it to be "bound" by the edges. However, it keeps clipping and goes beyond the screen.

I made the picturebox square and used the dimensions of the picture of the car, which is centered in the picturebox) to base the model of the code. The picturebox is 100x100 and the picture of the car (when facing sideways) is roughly 50x100. For example, if the car is going sideways against the edges of the screen, I would make the Y location of the picturebox -25. However, I feel that this is too inconvenient, because I may need to change the picture of the car.

```
Point pNewLoc = carLocation;

int iX = Width - pbCar.Width;
int iY = Height - pbCar.Height;

if (pNewLoc.X <= 0 || pNewLoc.X >= iX)
{
    if (pNewLoc.X <= 0)
    {
        if (iDirection == CarDirection.UP || iDirection == CarDirection.DOWN)
        {
            pNewLoc.X = -25;
        }
        else
        {
            pNewLoc.X = 0;
        }
    }
    if (pNewLoc.X >= iX)
    {
        if (iDirection == CarDirection.UP || iDirection == CarDirection.DOWN)
        {
            pNewLoc.X = iX + 25;
        }
        else
        {
            pNewLoc.X = iX;
        }
    }
}

if (pNewLoc.Y <= 0 || pNewLoc.Y >= iY)
{
    if (pNewLoc.Y <= 0)
    {
        if (iDirection == CarDirection.LEFT || iDirection == CarDirection.RIGHT)
        {
            pNewLoc.Y = -25;
        }
        else
        {
            pNewLoc.Y = 0;
        }
    }
    if (pNewLoc.Y >= iY)
    {
        if (iDirection == CarDirection.LEFT || iDirection == CarDirection.RIGHT)
        {
            pNewLoc.Y = iY + 25;
        }
        else
        {
            pNewLoc.Y = iY;
        }
    }
}

carLocation = pNewLoc;
```

This code works just fine, but I feel it's too long and is too inconvenient.

Comment: Use `ClientSize` of the form.

Comment: The first two if statements (`if (pNewLoc.X <= 0 || pNewLoc.X >= iX)` and `(pNewLoc.Y <= 0 || pNewLoc.Y >= iY)`) are redundant and you can remove them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is working, then, it can definetly be summarized:

```
int verticalDirection = Convert.ToInt32(iDirection == CarDirection.UP || iDirection == CarDirection.DOWN);
int horizontalDirection = Convert.ToInt32(iDirection == CarDirection.LEFT || iDirection == CarDirection.RIGHT);
if (pNewLoc.X <= 0)
{
    pNewLoc.X = -25 * verticalDirection;
}
else
{
    pNewLoc.X = iX + 25 * verticalDirection;
}
if (pNewLoc.Y <= 0)
{
    pNewLoc.Y = -25 * horizontalDirection;
}
else
{
    pNewLoc.Y = iY + 25 * horizontalDirection;
}
```

If you change the size of the picture, then you don't have to use a constant like `25` but declare a variable which is dependent on the size of the car picture.

Comment: Thank you for the help!